# flex error "start-condition stack underflow" with "%option full" on parsing files with chinese character

Tags: flex-lexer

I have a flex scanner that run correctly for a long time, even on files with some Chinese characters.
Recently I want to make it faster, and I add the "%option full", it indeed get 3X faster. but may fail on some files with comments that contain chinese characters.

The error message is "start-condition stack underflow".

I add some printing statement to my lex source code, and find that the scanner print this error in some start condiiton SC, but it have NOT run any code segment that contain "yy_push_state(SC)". So I think there may be some overflow in the flex buffer.

So what to do?

Answer (score 0):

For historical reasons (or something), if you use `%option full` or `%option fast`, then flex will default to producing a 7-bit scanner (i.e. `%option 7bit`).

That's really unsafe, since the 7-bit scanner does not even attempt to verify that the scanned text consists only of 7-bit ("ASCII") characters, and its behaviour in the case that it encounters a character with the high-order bit set is undefined. That will definitely happen if your input is UTF-8 or multibyte.

So you need to specify `%option 8bit full`. This will increase the size of your scanner tables, but these days that might not matter much. You might want to try `%option 8bit full ecs` as an intermediate setting. (I'm pretty sure that `8bit` is not necessary with `ecs`, but it can't hurt.)